# Converting a repository from git to subversion

Tags: svn, git, version-control

Reasons for doing this aside, is there a reasonable way to **convert an entire git repository to subversion**?

I can find only tons on information on migrating *from* subversion *to* git, and exchanging changesets between the two, but not for doing a simple conversion of the entire git repository to svn.

Comment: Duplicated here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661018/pushing-an-existing-git-repository-to-svn/1056817#1056817

Comment: Sad that you had to preface with "Reasons for doing this aside" in order to prevent a flame war or such...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The general problem with doing conversions this direction is that Git repositories can contain more than just a linear history of revisions, as Subversion would expect. Multiple ancestries with divergent histories and frequent merge commits are all possible, which can't be easily represented in a Subversion repository.

For simple cases where you do have a linear history in your Git repository, you can use `git-svn dcommit` to push the lot up to an otherwise empty Subversion repository.

Comment: Sorry to stir this up again after a few years, but can you give a concrete example of how to do this? Say I have a clone of a git repository at ~/my-git-repo, and I want to copy the commit history into some SVN repo, say svn://foo.com/empty-svn-repo/

Comment: @SchighSchagh: Have a look at this recent question, it might be more suited to what you need: [possible to recreate svn repository from (full) git-svn clone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13284762/possible-to-recreate-svn-repository-from-full-git-svn-clone)

Answer (score 6):

It's very easy to perform with [SubGit](http://subgit.com).

```
$ svnadmin create svn.repo
$ subgit configure svn.repo
$ nano svn.repo/conf/subgit.conf to specify a path to your bare repository (you may use "git clone --bare <URL>" if you have none locally)
$ subgit install svn.repo
```

After conversion your SVN and linked Git repository will be in sync: every Git push will be translated to SVN commit and vice versa. To break translation run

```
$ subgit uninstall svn.repo
```

While translation SubGit will try to preserve commit dates, tags, ignores, merges, EOLs, branches and so on, as it is possible. I can't say the same about git-svn repository.

Comment: This doesn't work. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/11084905/785194 for a working subgit solution.