# How can I migrate a git repo to svn with FULL COMMITS?

Tags: git, svn

I had read 'Migrate a Git repo to a SVN one' post:
http://sandrotosi.blogspot.com/2010/02/migrate-git-repo-to-svn-one.html

It just imports the working copy contents of git repo to svn repo, and generates just one commit of svn. That sucks, because I can just copy files and add to git repo with git's commands(add and commit) to achieve the same goal.

Is there any method to migrate a git repo to svn with FULL COMMITS?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting a repository from git to subversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498110/converting-a-repository-from-git-to-subversion)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pushing an existing git repository to SVN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661018/pushing-an-existing-git-repository-to-svn)

Comment: Thank you and @jonrsharpe , I had found the correct answer and update my question context, thank you very much!

Comment: Then accept the duplicate and upvote Dardo's answer, but it's not appropriate to put answers in questions.